# Possible to separate D+ and D- on 2 layer board?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, impedance-matching, usb-c

I am trying to make a PCB adapter, where the connections are USB-C, so need to cross connect the D+ and D- on both connectors.
Is it possible to run D+ on top layer, and D- on bottom layer?
Attached pictures of stackup and current layout.

My guess is if I make sure the distance between the 2 copper layers adheres to the required gap between D+ and D- it should work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You cannot satisfy controlled low impedances without a ground plane under traces with this geometry

Comment: Never use two layer boards for signals above 10MHz. You need a proper ground plane and route them close together (differential signal)

Comment: What's the speed? USB FS, HS, SuperSpeed, ...? USB FS is 12 MHz and usually no problem even if you don't correctly control the impedance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to run D+ on top layer, and D- on bottom layer?
> Attached pictures of stackup and current layout.

You need a reference plane of some sort, and decoupling capacitors. The reference plane should be referenced to ground. When diff pairs switch, then need a return current to maintain rise time. Also USB 3.0 needs to have impedance control (for transmission lines (90 Ohms) and should be length matched.

Here are some [guidelines for USB 3.0 routing.](http://pcb1001.blogspot.com/2011/09/superspeed-usb-3-design-guide.html)
And some other [guidelines](https://training.ti.com/sites/default/files/docs/usb_layout_basics.pdf)

Comment: The length matchening and impedance matching is clear to me, just didn't get to the lenght matchening yet. Was more interested in the possibility of seperating D+ and D- on different layers. Solved the issue by just going for 4 layer board and placing connectors differently to make routing easier and cleaner. Still thanks for the advice and links.